# I want to make my highmap as a google map with all the details. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to make a map of France with highmaps and I would like to make my map more attractive. Example: Google maps. Is it possible? I didn't find anything in the documentation. Thanks you for answers.

Comment: Hi @Kirill Kirs, Unfortunately Highmaps don't have any connection to Google API. In general you can add an idea here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks you for the answer! That's what I thought... I'll try google maps api or open street map.